# How to open android TeamViewer QuickSupport with Chrome intents (deep link) or any other way from a browser

Tags: android, android-intent, google-chrome-app

We are trying to get TeamViewer QuickSupport app to open on an android device using a deep link in a web page. Referring to android Chrome [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) we tried using this link:

```
intent:#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market;end
```

in

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market;end"> Open support </a>
```

But this opens google Play Store and redirects to TeamViewer QuickSupport (not a bad thing, but not what we are looking for) even if the app is installed. I know that I can open the app with that package name since I can open it in one of our native android apps.

Does anybody know if TeamViewer supports this or is there any other way to open an app on android using a web page? Nothing special needs to be done here, just open the main view of an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this url and worked in my vue.js app. It directly opens the app if it is installed.

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.teamviewer.launch.qs;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;end"> Open support </a>
```